# Meaning of "Auf ihrer Feier"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Sie hatte eine Niederlage erwartet, aber mit mehr als 20 Prozentpunkten Abstand zu Bernie Sanders dann doch nicht eine so schwere Schlappe: Für Hillary Clinton war die Vorwahl in New Hampshire ein Debakel. **Auf ihrer Feier** lächelte sie die Pleite weg, aber klar ist: Sie wird ihre Kampagne neu justieren und eine echte Botschaft entwickeln müssen.

What does *Auf ihrer Feier* mean here? The text piece is taken from [here](http://www.spiegel.de/politik/ausland/us-vorwahldrama-fuenf-lehren-aus-new-hampshire-a-1076616.html).

Comment: Please tell us why a grammar book/dictionary didn’t help you

Comment: Well, somehow I decided that this was an idiom and has a special meaning. I could not find it online though. It is clear why now - it is not an idiom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### On her party.

Feier = party, celebration, ceremony

> Lisa lädt all ihre Freundinnen zu ihrer Geburtstags**feier** ein.
>   Lisa invites all her friends to her birthday **party**.
>
> Zur **Feier** des fünfzigjährigen Bestehens der Firma war auch der Bundespräsident geladen.
>   The Federal President was invited to the **celebration** of 50 years existence of the company.
>
> Die **Feier** der Krönung der Königin war sehr pompös.
>   The **ceremony** of the queens crowning was very pompous.

Answer (score 4):

The party which was prepared to celebrate her expected (pre-) election victory: was her Party. 
So

> Auf ihrer Feier

refers to this party and simply means

> At her party